# How does Google Custom Search Engine solves XSS?

Tags: javascript, jsonp, xss, cors, google-custom-search

I have been thinking about building a service that would use a similar approach as used by Google CSE - https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/rendering  I have not been able to understand how Google gets around the XSS. Is it because they host the JS file that they are able to write into the DIV?  Are they using CORS headers?  Please share your inputs if you have experience using this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It uses a combination of same-origin requests and jsonp. It requests www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1element and www.google.com/uds via the `<script>` tag and then those scripts are allowed to request from www.googleapis.com and www.google.com respectively.